# I have two different types of users, i.e. Driver and Passenger. I want in the login page if it's the driver's login only driver should authorized

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I know it's a duplicate question, I already tried the available solution but not able to get the success so I need help, please. Thank you.
I have two different users in databases. I want the driver should be only authorized into Driver's login and Passenger should be only authorized into Passegner's login. If they try to use another login page they will get an error message.

```
    ...Driver's login
```

databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("All Drivers");

```
    userLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail.getText().toString(),
                    userPass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(driverLogin.this, driverHome.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(driverLogin.this, "User name and Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

During registration, register a "userType" variable for the user. The "userType" will be stored within the Database Tree. That way you will be able to call it to verify the type of user during the login session.

After the user is Authenticated via Firebase Email Authentication, an If else statement will be run within the "loginUser" function which will determine if the Authenticated user was registered as a "Driver" or "Passenger".

Comment: Thank you for looking. The user type is already stored I'll try with if-else. Hope it'll work.

Comment: I tried but it's not working correctly. The if statement is not running. Can you look at this for me if possible? Thank you!

Comment: if (task.isSuccessful()) {
 if (firebaseDatabase.getReference("All Drivers").child("userType").equals(type)) {
 startActivity(new Intent(driverLogin.this, driverHome.class)); } else {
   Toast.makeText(driverLogin.this, "You are not authorized to login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(driverLogin.this, MainActivity.class)); }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(driverLogin.this, "User name and Password do not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

Comment: It's skipping the nested if and directly switching on the nested else. I appreciate your help, thank you.